# Applications of fuzzy logic/set theory in pure math?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I read in some posts on this website how fuzzy set theory is related to various reall life applications, e.g. computer programming, robotics, etc. I am wondering if anyone who is fairly into fuzzy set theory could provide any pure math applications of fuzzy set theory and NOT real-life applications. By "pure math applications", I mean how it relates to other branches of math, e.g. abstract algebra, analysis, combinatorics, etc. In your opinion, how much value is there in studying fuzzy set theory for pure mathematician?

Same question applies to fuzzy logic. Thank you

Comment: I would argue that we can view fuzzy logic/set theory as a pure topic in its own right.

Comment: I think the divide between much of theoretical computer science and pure mathematics is baseless. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.4953.pdf